# How to aggregate data by date and string multiIndex using Pandas, then print to .csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with three relevant columns: a date (Python datetime object), a String representing a type, and a numeric value. I need to group the data frame by month, then by type. I then want to sum each of those groups. For example, I have:

```
DATE       TYPE       VALUE
1/31/2016  "yellow"   10
2/28/2016  "yellow"   10
2/28/2016  "red"      20
3/31/2016  "blue"     20
3/31/2016 "yellow"    10
2/28/2016  "blue"     20
2/28/2016  "red"      10
1/31/2016  "blue"     10
2/28/2016  "yellow"   20
1/31/2016  "blue"     10
```

And I want:

```
DATE       TYPE       SUM
1/31/2016  "blue"     20
1/31/2016  "yellow"   10
2/28/2016  "blue"     20
2/28/2016  "red"      30
2/28/2016  "yellow"   30
3/31/2016  "blue"     20
3/31/2016  "yellow"   10
```

What is the best way to aggregate this data by month and type, and then export to a csv file? I had issues with groupby because I could not print the GroupBy object to a .csv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to convert your DATE to a datetime, you can then `groupby` on month and TYPE and then call `sum`:

```
In [83]:
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df

Out[83]:
        DATE    TYPE  VALUE
0 2016-01-31  yellow     10
1 2016-02-28  yellow     10
2 2016-02-28     red     20
3 2016-03-31    blue     20
4 2016-03-31  yellow     10
5 2016-02-28    blue     20
6 2016-02-28     red     10
7 2016-01-31    blue     10
8 2016-02-28  yellow     20
9 2016-01-31    blue     10

In [85]:
df.groupby([df['DATE'].dt.month, df['TYPE']]).sum().reset_index()

Out[85]:
   DATE    TYPE  VALUE
0     1    blue     20
1     1  yellow     10
2     2    blue     20
3     2     red     30
4     2  yellow     30
5     3    blue     20
6     3  yellow     10
```